# Hyperfine structure of spectral lines

Tags: atomic-physics

In hyperfine spliting of level, the order of hfs(hyperfine spliting) level in some hypermultiplts is normal(smallest
**F** level deepest) while in others it is inverted(largest**F** level deepest).what is reason behind it.